# How to save show default value in edittext but then user input once they've entered it?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I am new to this and trying to create a simple android application where the first activity has a link to the user's settings/input in the second activity. Here I've made a few EditText where it says for instance: "Name of Contact" like this:

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name of Contact"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

I am able to save this through sharedpreferences but the question is, how can I have the user input (in the edittext) displayed next time the user enters the activity screen? And if they have not entered anything, keep the original text (here: "Name of Contact")?

Update:
Thanks for the tips. However, from what I understand the display shows the XML file. So if I call the saved info from sharedpreferences in the java file, how do I "transfer" this to the XML file

Thanks guys

Comment: you already answered you question **sharedpreferences** just implement it. Save the value in onPause method and in oncreate check if a value exists if yes show the text.

Answer (score 2):

For starters use the property `android:hint="What is up?"` to display placeholder text when the field is empty. It's hard to say exactly how to load your value again with the information you've provided, but the gist of it is that you should store the value in some way (shared preferences will work), then retrieve that value again when the view is presented.

If you're using View Fragments, you'd probably do this in `onCreateView` and `onResume`. In those override methods, read from shared preferences, if there is a value present, set the EditText text property to that value.

[Fragment Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)